# Infinite loading using Authorization header with swagger 2.0

Tags: flask, swagger, authorization

I'm programming a swagger documentation with swagger 2.0 and the request containing an authorization header doesn't seem to work properly. In fact, when I add the token in the Authorize header then execute the query, it says loading indefinitely.

[Loading request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1ZXm.png)

I've been facing the same problem for 2 days and I don't find any topic dealing about my issue.

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
    "description": "Swagger API",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Swagger API",
    "license": {
        "name": "MIT",
        "url": "https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
    }
},

"securityDefinitions": {
    "Bearer": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "name": "Authorization",
        "in": "header"
    }
},

"paths": {
    "/api/login": {
        "post": {
            "tags": ["Login"],
            "summary": "Returns JWT",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "in": "body",
                    "name": "Login body",
                    "description": "Login request used to obtain JWT",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/Login"
                    }
                }
            ],

            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "Success"
                }
            }
        }
    },

    "/api/devices": {
        "get": {
            "tags": ["Devices"],
            "summary": "Returns all devices",
            "security": {
                "Bearer": []
            },
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "GET success"
                },
                "401": {
                    "description": "Missing header with jwt"
                }
            }
        },
        "post": {
            "tags": ["Devices"],
            "summary": "Deploy all devices",
            "security": {
                "Bearer": []
            },
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "in": "body",
                    "name": "Devices POST body",
                    "description": "Deploy devices",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/Devices"
                    }
                }
            ],

            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "Device deployment succeed"
                },
                "401": {
                    "description": "Missing header with jwt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},

"components": {
    "Login": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "login": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "email": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "password": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    "Devices": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "devices": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "devEUILSBList": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "applicationID": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "deviceProfileID": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Complementary information :

- The backend is running with Flask
- Swagger 2.0

Comment: If you paste your spec into https://editor.swagger.io, you will see there are syntax errors. Specifically: 1) Top-level `components` section should actually be named `definitions`; 2) The `security` value should be an array: `"security": [ {"Bearer": []} ]`. Fix these errors and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works as a charm now!!